# Using linq on asp.net generated tables

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

Would it be wise to use linq to sql on the tables generated by asp.net reg_sql tool? i would like to be able to do some operations on the dbo.aspnet_webEvents_Event table (purging the data base on date or event type for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would be perfectly wise and acceptable, but just make sure that any operations you call on the linq objects based on reg_sql-generated tables don't interfere with the logic in any of the reg_sql-generated sprocs operating on dbo.aspnet_webEvents_Event table or related tables.